# Can someone tell me where in my "proof" that ZF is inconsistent I went wrong?

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

I've come up with a supposed "proof" of the inconsistency of ZF, and I'm not exactly sure I went wrong. I'm not claiming to have proved it, obviously. I know it's wrong somewhere. This thought just came up into my mind and I thought it was neat. I'm only at the first-year graduate level in set theory, keep in mind. Here goes:

Let $f(n)$ be the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $V_{\alpha}$ is a $\Sigma_n$ elementary substructure of $V$. By replacement, the range of this function is a set. Let $\beta$ be the supremum of this set. So, $V_{\beta}$ is an elementary substructure of $V$, hence it's a model of ZF. ZF proves its own consistency, so it is inconsistent.

Comment: Is "$V_\alpha$ a $\Sigma_n$-elementary substructure of $V$" expressible as a first-order formula with parameters $\alpha$ and $n$? How have you avoided Tarski's undefinability theorem?

Comment: Theeeeere it is. And, for the record, I have never seen Tarski's undecidability theorem. I understand it.

Comment: This is a common point of confusion: for each $n$, the statement is expressible as a formula, but it’s a different formula for each $n$, not a single formula with $n$ as a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has to do with the undefinability of truth, and the merely schematic definability of $\Sigma_n$-truth.

Recall that the axiom of Replacement says, roughly, that if a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ defines a function $F: V\to V$, then on any set $A$, the pointwise image $F''A$ is a set. To apply Replacement to the function $f$ as in the OP, we presumably will need a single formula $\Phi(x,y)$ that's equivalent to saying "$y$ is the least ordinal such that $V_y$ is $\Sigma_x$-elementary to $V$."

But a special case of Tarski's undefinability theorem says, for any formula $\varphi(x,y)$, the following will not hold:

> For any natural number $n$ and ordinal $\alpha$, $\varphi(n,\alpha)$ if and only if $V_\alpha$ is a $\Sigma_n$-elementary substructure of $V$.

The point here is that there's no *single* formula that does what's required for the OP's argument to go through.

The more common form of Tarski's theorem says that there is no formula $True(x,y)$ such that for any (code of a) formula $\psi$ and any set $a$, $True(\psi, a)$ if and only if $\psi(a)$ is true. In slogan form: truth is not definable.

Now the more subtle point is that for each (meta-theoretic) natural number $n$, we do have a formula $True_n(x,y)$, satisfying

> $True_n(\psi, a)$ if and only if $\psi$ is a $\Sigma_n$ formula and $\psi(a)$ is true.

Since from the definition $\Sigma_n$-truth we can go on and define the notion of "$\Sigma_n$-elementary to $V$", what we do have, then, is that for each $n$, there is a formula $\Phi_n(y)$ that is equivalent to saying "$y$ is the least ordinal such that $V_y$ is $\Sigma_n$-elementary to $V$."

The key observation is that, when it comes to $\Sigma_n$-truth in $V$, we need a separate formula for each $n$.

On the other hand, we can define truth for any set-sized structure. So this argument does have a version that's somewhat applicable. For example, one can show that the least $\kappa$ such that $V_\kappa\vDash \mathsf{ZFC}$ (if exists) has cofinality $\omega$. One way to show this is by an argument that's similar to the OP's.

> suppose for contradiction that the least such $\kappa$ has uncountable cofinality. Then define $f(n)$ to be the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha$ is a $\Sigma_n$-elementary substructure of $V_\kappa$. Then by replacement (in V), the image of $f$ forms a countable set of ordinals. And since $\kappa$ has uncountable cofinality, the supremum $\lambda$ of that set is bounded below $\kappa$. And because $V_\lambda$ is an increasingly elementary chain of structures, we have $V_\lambda$ is an elementary substructure of $V_\kappa$, and hence $V_\lambda\vDash\mathsf{ZFC}$, contradicting the minimality of $\kappa$.

This version of the argument goes through, because in this case we do have a single formula $\Phi(x,y)$ that's equivalent to saying "$y$ is the least ordinal such that $V_y$ is $\Sigma_x$-elementary to $V_\kappa$." This is precisely because truth in a set-sized structure is definable by a single formula.